# how to align the AppBar title to right in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 50.0,          
          title: const Text(
            'This is the title !',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Please see help center. How to ask questions:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your title in a Align and apply Alignment.centerRight to it

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Text(
            "My title",
            
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped to solve my problem
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
  return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Text(
        "title",

    ),),),
      body: getText("text"),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped to solve my problem
cheers.